# Store neighbor coordinates of mines in a list

Tags: list, tuples

I'd like to be able to store pairs of coordinates (x,y) that represent the neighbors of mines in a minesweeper app. [HW Instructions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YoxCL.png)

I set up an if statement to check if a mine is present first. I started creating a list of neighbor coordinates.

```
 private List<Tuple<int,int>> getneighbors(int x, int y)
    {
        if (isMinePresent(x,y) == true)
        {
            List<Tuple<int, int>> neighbors = new List<Tuple<int, int>> () {x+1,y},{x+1,y+1} //etc;

            {

            }

        }
    }
}
```

I'd like to make a list of several pairs of coordinates - each representing a neighbor. Unfortunately, I got an error: "C# does not contain a constructor that takes 2 arguments".

Comment: Is there some particular reason you would choose to do it this way?

Comment: It was in HW and I have to use a Tuple to store the coordinates.

Comment: Of course it is homework. This is why computer science programs produce people who have no idea how to design software. I’ve done software for 15 years and never have I ever needed nor would I have desired to use a tuple.

Comment: And this is just my rant against com sci. Has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: Yeah, my prof has no idea what he's doing lmao. He just threw Tuple's at us without learning any of the basics.

Comment: That’s too bad. If you want my advice, switch to engineering, so you learn how to design, then take a software job out of college so you can get paid well to do it 

Comment: Thanks for the advice :) But what is a better way to store the coordinates for the neighbors in a list?

Comment: Would you be able to update the question to include the actual homework question?

Comment: I included an image of the assignment

Comment: Ok, this is the entirety of it? I don’t see any requirement to determine a mine is present, so that would be out of scope

Answer (score 0):

> This method takes the coordinates and returns all valid neighbor coordinates.

The question that needs to be answered here is how to determine what are the valid neighbors? For that, a little bit of logic is called for - a square has neighbors in its row, the row prior, and the next row. Potentially up to 8 neighbors are possible.

Take a look at this [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-aypzw5?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) and play around with it a bit. I wrote it in TypeScript, but the concepts are directly applicable to C#.

I define a neighbor as "valid" if its coordinate is within one of the starting coordinate but NOT out of bounds.

```
getNeighbors(inX: number, inY: number) {

    // Get proper bounds
    var lowerX = Math.max(0, inX-1);
    var upperX = Math.min(inX+1, this.size);
    var lowerY = Math.max(0, inY-1);
    var upperY = Math.min(inY+1, this.size);

    var xCoords = Enumerable.rangeTo(lowerX, upperX);
    var yCoords = Enumerable.rangeTo(lowerY, upperY);          

    var result = new Array<Coordinate>();
    xCoords.forEach(x => {
       yCoords.forEach(y => {
         if (x !== inX || y !== inY) {
           result.push({x, y});
         }
       });
    });

    return result;
  }
```